# How to force redirection after POST Form Method with PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to be redirected to the URL in output of this POST Method Form.

```
<form id="redirectForm" action="<?php echo $_GET['URL']; ?>" method="post" name="myform">
  <input type="hidden" name="ORDER_ID" value="<?php echo $_GET['ORDER_ID']; ? >"/>
</form>
```

In console, i have my url Statut 200 Get Method :

```
https://www.example.com/send/forward?URL=https://domaine.com/home_card2&ORDER_ID=000&
```

In controller i have :

```
 public function forward(Request $request){
   return view ('forward',['data'=>$request]);
 }
```

My Route :

```
Route::get('/send/forward', 'HomeController@forward');
```

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: `header('Location: ...'); exit();`  in Laravel [redirect()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects) ?   Not sure what the problem is here?

Comment: I'm not reirected to https://www.example.com/send/forward?URL=https://domaine.com/home_card2&ORDER_ID=000& after post form 
The url appears only in console

Comment: By the way for security you should not allow $_GET be directly used without removing newlines (`\r\n` which i believe is defined in the HTTP protocol but also remove `\n` and `\r` for extra safety as browser could also use those as valid "newlines") first in a `header('Location: ...');`   also not sure if with is safe on Laravel in the `redirect()` as HTTP Response Splitting/HTTP header injection could happen if you are using a unsafe PHP version..

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in routes if you use post request the you need to use routes

```
Route::post('/send/forward', 'HomeController@forward');
```

OR

```
Route::any('/send/forward', 'HomeController@forward');
```

please replace your routes routes.php